# Uninstall Kubuntu from a dual-boot with Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uninstall

I have a multi-boot system with Windows 7, Ubuntu 15.04, and Kubuntu 15.04 installed in that order.  At the moment, I think my **system boots through Kubuntu's GRUB**.  My Windows is installed on an NTFS partition (sda2); and all within an extended partition sda2: I have my Kubuntu ext4 (sda7), Ubuntu ext4 (sda6), and swap (sda5) partitions.

How can I properly uninstall Kubuntu leaving behind Windows and Ubuntu?

I don't think I can simply delete my Kubuntu partition using GParted from Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub` can I?

Comment: Correct method is to boot into install you want to keep. Then install its copy of grub to MBR before deleting the one that will not work. `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`  But you should not have to reinstall either. Just use live installer to restore grub. Either manually or with Boot-Repair. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Boot the computer from Ubuntu.

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub-common grub2-common
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
sudo gparted
```

Delete the partition using GParted, close it and continue running:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the partition using GParted and run `sudo update-grub`.
But first of all create an Ubuntu distro bootable drive and back up your data - *anything can happen*.
If `sudo update-grub` does not work when you run it from the installed Ubuntu then boot from the bootable drive you created and run the command. That works when the latter fails.

Comment: This did not work.
The subsequent boot displayed something like "partition not found".
I cannot run sudo update-grub from the bootable USB (some file can't be found - I forget now).
Did you read the part where I mentioned that it was Kubuntu's GRUB that I was booting through, and not Ubuntu's?
Turns out reinstalling Ubuntu does the job, but a better method would be nice.