# How to remobe lubuntu 20.04 from ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: updates, lubuntu, 20.04, uninstall

I tried uninstalling lubuntu desktop from ubuntu with various commands on google but any command didn't seem to work.What can i do to remove lubuntu from ubuntu?

Comment: `sudo apt remove lubuntu-desktop` will remove the Lubuntu desktop.  The `plymouth` screen will remain until it's changed (it's like a wallpaper, an was installed with the desktop, but isn't removed on package removal, so just change it).  You haven't exactly said what your issue is, is it the `plymouth` screen you're asking about (ie. it hides messages on boot & shutdown if enabled..)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uninstall Kubuntu from a dual-boot with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653756/uninstall-kubuntu-from-a-dual-boot-with-ubuntu)

Comment: @guiverc please look at https://askubuntu.com/q/1255883/248158

Answer (score 0):

Unless you took note of all packages that were installed when you installed  `lubuntu-desktop`, it will be difficult to granularly remove any packages that were brought in during the installation of the package.

`lubuntu-desktop` is a meta-package. It depends on all packages that are considered an essential part of the lubuntu desktop. Thus, simply installing `lubuntu-desktop` will pull in all these packages, in so far they are not installed already. However, removing `lubuntu-desktop` will only remove the tiny package itself. Because most of the "main" application packages (e.g., the editor, system tools, ...) are marked as "manually installed", it is not possible to automatically remove them with `apt autoremove` after removing `lubuntu-desktop.

**Precautions next time you want to install an additional desktop environment**

Install using the `sudo apt install` command. That lists all packages that are going to be installed. Copy and paste the names of these packages to a text file. If you want to undo the installation, then just remove all these packages.

**At this time, where you already removed the lubuntu-package**

There is not a lot you can do yourself. If you run `sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop` again, only the packages that may have been removed by an `sudo apt autoremove` will be listed. Many of the packages still are installed.

You could look at all dependencies of `lubuntu-desktop`. However, these will also include packages that are also needed by your current desktop environment.

You could ask another user to see what packages `lubuntu-desktop` brings in. However, that list will depend on the desktop currently installed on the system of that other user, *and* on applications that user may have added or removed.

*Removing applications followed by autoremove*

What you can do, is manually remove applications you know came with Lubuntu (or eventually applications you do not seem to miss). A subsequent `sudo apt autoremove` will then automatically remove these dependencies (libraries etc.) that are not anymore required by other installed packages.

This way, you can go a large way in effectively removing the Lubuntu desktop up to the point that, as a user, you do not see traces anymore. However, there is no certainty that all packages effectively are gone. That is, from a practical viewpoint, not really a concern.

*Boot screen: plymouth*

Removing the packages `plymouth-theme-lubuntu-logo` and `plymouth-theme-lubuntu-text` will cause your boot screen appearance to revert to the original.