# Lubuntu Minimal on mini.iso after 18.04 - lxde or lxqt?

Tags: lubuntu, lxde

I am a big fan of the Lubuntu Minimal Desktop from the mini.iso.  For 18.04, it is still using LXDE, which I am grateful for.  Does anyone know if this will change to LXQT beginning with 18.10, as is the plan with the main distro?  Or, might it stay LXDE (I hope...)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, if what you want is still available, it will be LXQt only in Lubuntu versions higher than 18.04. But a Lubuntu team member will give you a complete answer shortly.

Comment: I had a conversation in the mailing list that leads me to believe that it will be LXQt in the future. There will be no further development with LXDE, though we should be able to easily install it so long as it remains in the repos.

Comment: If you're asking about https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/lubuntu-core, it was last available with bionic/18.04 which will be supported until 2021-April. Lubuntu uses LXQt from 1810 up as @DKBose mentioned and no such package exists after 18.04.  Lubuntu 18.04 was also the last with the alternate ISO which allowed installs on machines with less than 768MB of ram (it wasn't even re-spun for 18.04.1 or later ISOs, just the original 18.04)

Comment: If you're worried about lightness, I used old single-core pentium M, 1GB ram laptops to test Lubuntu 18.10 & 19.04, and in my subjective opinion it was the lightest Ubuntu flavor available (Xubuntu was the only other capable o running on those laptops though).  For later/subsequent cycles I finally added memory as few people would use 1GB ram laptops these days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're asking about https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/lubuntu-core, it was last available with bionic/18.04 which will be supported until 2021-April.

Lubuntu uses **LXQt** from 18.10 up as @DKBose mentioned and no such package exists after 18.04.

Lubuntu 18.04 LTS was also the last with the alternate ISO which allowed installs on machines with less than 768MB of ram (*it wasn't even re-spun for 18.04.1 or later ISOs, just the original 18.04*) See https://lubuntu.me/taking-a-new-direction/

If you're worried about lightness, I used old single-core pentium M, 1GB ram laptops to test Lubuntu 18.10 & 19.04, and in my subjective opinion it was the lightest Ubuntu flavor available (*Xubuntu was the only other capable of running on those laptops though; MATE had already ported to GTK3 so was painful on those under-powered & ancient laptops*). For later/subsequent cycles I finally added memory as few people would use 1GB ram laptops these days, though I did push a pentium 4 box up to eoan/19.10 too.

LXDE is currently on *life-support* It was noted by *pcman* [some GTK3 patches were submitted years ago](https://blog.lxde.org/2014/11/18/status-update-for-lxde/), and pcman actually started porting it to GTK3 but noted the performance hit (*I can't currently find the blog on this, I'll add it if I find it*), so it was re-reported to Qt5 which performed much better. Most of the LXDE team then joined with Razor-Qt team creating a new LXQt team & project.  Lubuntu wants to remain light, which today means LXQt/Qt5.

LXDE may still survive if it's converted to GTK3, however I personally suspect it's days are numbered (*in Debian/Ubuntu*).  Lubuntu now uses LXQt/Qt5, Xubuntu is now all GTK3 (since 19.10), and the main project that has kept GTK2 libraries *mostly-patched* is still `gimp` ([GNU Image Manipulation program](https://www.gimp.org/)) which is nearing its GTK3 port completion. Once the port of `gimp` to GTK3 is done, we may see Debian/Ubuntu EOL GTK2 & start removing all GTK2 libraries which will cause LXDE to disappear as well (this won't occur before April-2021, though packages are likely to remain in existing repositories for the full life of those systems just as `python2` & Qt4 packages did; what happened with those are what I'd expect to happen with all GTK2 based packages).

For LXDE to survive in Debian/Ubuntu, it'll require a community member to package it's GTK3 port when it's completed (*an unknown date in the future*) which will likely involve even more work if it's after removal of existing packages, but that's just my opinion!  (*it may be packaged via PPA as that's a lot easier having a very loose security model*)

The real answer to your *minimal package* question though is probably best answered by the already provided [Taking a New Direction](https://lubuntu.me/taking-a-new-direction/) blog.

An alternative way of achieving that however would be to

> Not installing the Recommends of `lubuntu-desktop` has a similar effect.

Quoting @wxl from https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/what-happened-to-the-meta-mackage-lubuntu-core-in-20-04-lts/1045

Comment: Great answer, but sad news. LXDE is what attracted me to Ubuntu/Lubuntu in the first place.  It appears that the menu system in Ubuntu MATE is similar enough to keep me happy though. Had I tried MATE out first, I might have started with it

Comment: @OrganicMarble what's special about LXDE's menu? The menu in Lubuntu (LXQt version) is very much like that, isn't it?

Comment: @DKBose I have complete control over the LXDE menu, which is what I require. I looked briefly at LXQt in Lubuntu 20.04 and if that capability exists, it was not obvious. It may be there and I missed it though. Plus, the 20.04 betas of Lubuntu looked like they were made by a high school kid (the desktop).